# Which platform do I need to develop a website using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php

I want to develop a professional website using PHP and MySQL. Can I do it in Windows 7 (64-bit) or I need to install linux based OS. How to go for it.

Comment: No. Windows is an inadvisable plattform for developing "professional" websites. Unless of course, it also gets deployed on a Windows server.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in Server Fault?

Comment: @mario why? I've been doing it for years, and I'm entirely happy. Differences in configuration can be easily bridged using local and remote configuration files. There is no real downside to this IMO, except if you interface with the host OS's command line functions very extensively, or use PHP functions available only on a certain platform.

Comment: @Pekka: That's exactly what I was onto. It's often more optimal to just invoke Python (or Perl modules) from within PHP. And that's worlds easier on their native plattform. Sure, you can set up anything almost like that on Windows, but it's too much of a hassle. And I've seen quite a bit of code that's rather inefficient and most likely originated on a Windows development environment. - But of course the defintion of "professional website" is entirely debatable, and it was just a fill world in the question. So, anyway.

Comment: @mario I agree with you wherever system specific code is called, but can you make examples of PHP "code that's rather inefficient because it originated on Windows"? PHP is PHP, no matter where you develop it, and *meant* to be a portable language. The notion that a PHP project developed on Windows is somehow implicitly inferior in code quality compared to one developed in a Linux environment, or that there are degrees of professionality not reachable in a Windows environment, is nonsense.

Comment: @Pekka: You're right. But I didn't mean that as derogatory assessment. This was mostly about efficient implementations, as PHP has a native plattform. If it's "professional" to plattform glue (e.g. just runs on Linux due to excessive cmdline calls) elsewhise portable PHP scripts is another discussion. And btw, IMO the phrase "professional" is a buzzword as void in meaning as "enterprise". However as example, I'd like to finger point at osCommerce. Quite horrible in itself, but some coding styles seemed overly Windowsish. Can't remember/explain it though. So perception. Not a law.

Comment: @mario I'm still saying it's no problem at all to develop and test on Windows, and deploy to Linux. Regarding OSCommerce - you're going to have to come up with something harder than perception to blame "Windowsish" coding practices for its awful spaghetti code. :) As far as I can see, OSCommerce has nothing to do with Windows whatsoever, not even historically, and a vast majority of its installations is hosted and runs on Linux servers.

Comment: @mario but even if there are Windows- or Linux- or whatever-inspired parts in OSCommerce, it doesn't matter. A good PHP application doesn't have any platform specific quirks, but is just a good application. And those, as I say, you can develop on a Linux, Windows, or Mac OS/Unix machine. I personally vastly prefer Windows's user interface to Linux for everyday work. That Linux is the best environment to then *run* the application in production, being the native home to Apache, PHP and mySQL, that I agree with you on.

Comment: @Pekka: Ooops, this totally went offtopic ;)  - Anyway, remember about my osCommerce drama. That specific version contained some ASP to PHP converted code, which made it extra awful. - If you stick to WAMP, there's little compatibility issues. But Postgres or other DBs mean more trouble for Windows users. That's why for one of my applications, we had different database backends. Specifically one for files. The case-insensitivity of Wins' filesystem was a bug first, but proved more userfriendly, so got adapted with lots of effort for the Unix version. So pro argument for cross plattform dev;

Comment: While I'm happy to entertain the notion that the quality of one's tools affects the quality of one's product, I see absolutely no basis for arguing that a developer's choice of operating system could somehow affect the quality (or "professionalism") of the PHP code produced. The unsubstantiated arguments above reek of biased fanboyism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run an AMP Stack (Apache, mySQL, PHP) on Windows no problem. I have been doing this for ten years now. Running on Windows 7 64-bit is also no problem.

There are several pre-packaged installers available. My favourite is [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). They usually allow full customization where needed.

You can also download the stand-alone binaries of each product and install them manually. Makes for very, very good learning but is more work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Though a platform is the least thing you will need...

Comment: The journey of a thousand miles begins, truly, with a single step.  Preferably the first one.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned it is possible to develop Php and MySQL sites quite happily on Windows using something like XAMPP, even if they are later to be deployed on a Linux web server and I know a lot of people do this and it works great for them.

However I have found in the past you can run into problems later on this way.  For example, a lot of people who have only used Windows in the past can get caught out by case-sensitivity in Linux.  So your site runs great locally but then you start getting lots of 404 errors when you go live because for example, mypage.php is not the same as myPage.php any more.

At the other end of the development spectrum, you can achieve some really powerful functionality when you start to work the server a bit more - things like video encoding or audio conversion are possible using PHP (with a bit of help from some other apps) on both Windows and Linux but the ways that you would do it are different therefore your development environment becomes much less useful and again you run the risk of putting something live that doesn't work, even tho it runs fine when you test it locally.

Personally, I think it is always best to develop on as close an environment to the intended production server as you can to avoid any nasty surprises when you go live.

Answer (score 1):

Develop on the same platform you are going to be deploying to (if possible).  It'll make it extremely easy to deploy with less room for possible error.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 64-bit versions Apache/PHP/MySQL on Windows 7 is a bit of a pain, but you can easily install the 32-bit versions using XAMPP (as mentioned by Pekka) from apachefriends.org

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can use a light package, which content php, apache, mysql, pear. [link text](http://denwer.ru)